# Model object passed to HttpPost action is having null values

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model with properties declared, Controller actions. and View with Viewmodel specified. **I fill data in the form and submit, but model has only null values for all properties. If i try with view model i get same null values in HttpPost action.**
My Model:

```
public class Supplier
{
    public string SupplierSequenceNumber { get; set; }

    public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    public string SupplierActive { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        SupplierVM objSupplierVM = new SupplierVM();
        return View(objSupplierVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Supplier objSupplier)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My View:

```
 @model AIEComm.ViewModel.SupplierVM
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Supplier", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formAddSupplier" }))
{
   <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.objSupplier.SupplierName, new{@class = "control-label"})
             <div class="controls">
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.objSupplier.SupplierName, new { placeholder = "Swatch Style" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.objSupplier.SupplierName)
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.objSupplier.SupplierActive, new{@class = "control-label"})
             <div class="controls">
             @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.objSupplier.SupplierActive,new SelectList(AIEComm.Models.Utilities.YesNoSelectList,"Value","Text"),new{@class=""})
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.objSupplier.SupplierName)
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="control-group">
               <div class="controls">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="Add"/>
               </div>
           </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is the following code:

```
m => m.objSupplier.SupplierName
```

You're generating HTML elements with a model that is inside a ViewModel. This is a good approach, and your problem can be solved quite easily.

It's a good approach because you're keeping things organised, but it's not working because the above code is saying:

> Ok, using the `ViewModel` object (`m`), take the `objSupplier` object and then use the `SupplierName` property.

This is fine, but then when you're submitting data, you're saying (to the action):

> Hi, I have a `SupplierName` property. Please put this into the `objSupplier` object which you can find inside the `ViewModel` object.

To which the action says "Well, I am expecting an `objSupplier` object, but what's this ViewModel you speak of?"

A simple solution is to create a new partial view to generate your form. It's model type should be:

**_SupplierForm.cshtml**

```
@model Supplier

@* // The Form *@
```

In your View, continue to use the same ViewModel, but pass in the correct supplier model:

```
@model AIEComm.ViewModel.SupplierVM

@Html.Partial("_SupplierForm", Model.objSupplier)
```

Comment: Hai,I got it working by declaring properties for model and utilities in Viewmodel. Is it not good ?

Comment: That can work too. I prefer your original technique (with my suggestion) because it separates the models up and keeps things clean. Just my preference though.