# Model is Null in Httppost mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My Model is

```
public class IssueEntryModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OrderNumbers { get; set; }
    public string SelectedWorkOrder { get; set; }
    public string MaterialCode
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public List<GroupedIssueData> MaterialData { get; set; }
}
```

And the view is

```
@model InventoryEasy15.Models.IssueEntryModel

@{
    var issueData = Model.MaterialData;
    var workorders = Model.SelectedWorkOrder;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveIssueEntry", "IssueMaster",  FormMethod.Post, new { id = "issueEntryForm" }))
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < issueData.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@issueData[i].MaterialCode</td>
            <td>@issueData[i].MaterialDescription</td>
            <td>@issueData[i].Unit</td>
            <td>@issueData[i].ReqQty</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => issueData[i].IssueQty, new { style = "width:70px" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => issueData[i].IssueQty)</td>
            <td class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => issueData[i].isSavings)</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

And I have post method as

```
public ActionResult SaveIssueEntry(IssueEntryModel model)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

And the get contains the details to fill the view as

```
//Method Get the material details based on the work order id
public async Task<ActionResult> GetWorkOrderMaterialDetails(IssueEntryModel m)
{
```

During post to a new method , the model is becomes null, Any thoughts?

Comment: Though you didn't posted `GroupedIssueData` but try with: `@MaterialData[i].MaterialCode` etc. and [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372439/model-object-passed-to-httppost-action-is-having-null-values) can provide you some background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor uses the expression passed to the HTML helpers in order to build the proper name for the inputs that will allow the modelbinder to bind them properly on post. That means the expression needs to match the access method of the property *exactly*. By saving `Model.MaterialData` to the `issueData` variable and utilizing that, you're disrupting this. In other words, you're ending up with inputs named like `issueData[0].IssueQty`, instead of `MaterialData[0].IssueQty`. The modelbinder doesn't know what to do with `issueData` on post, because nothing on your model matches that.

Long and short, your textbox needs to be declared like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaterialData[i].IssueQty, ...)
```

Similarly for your checkbox:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MaterialData[i].isSavings)
```

Comment: Great this worked. One more question, <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaterialData[i].MaterialCode)</td> prints as MaterialCode not the details, I want to display this as label, except reqqty. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `DisplayFor`. `LabelFor` literally prints the property name.